# Date conversion from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I need to convert a date from *dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd*.
I am getting the input from a text box in *dd/mm/yyyy* format.When i try to convert it to *yyyy/mm/dd* i got the error *invalid date*.How can i convert it properly.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using now?

Comment: What did you try yourself ?

Comment: var start=request.param('startDate');
formatedStartDate = getYearMonthDate(new Date(start));


function getYearMonthDate(date){
var monthYear=date.getFullYear()+" "+date.getMonth()+  " "  + date.getDate();
    return monthYear;
}

Comment: `date="dd/mm/yyyy"; var newdate = date.split("/").reverse().join("-");`

Comment: @BhargavModi , please post it as an answer.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com done I didnot understood your moto behind it

Comment: @BhargavModi , Hello , If you put it as answer , it will be helpful for future visitors to see answer.Do you think they will be reading Comments to get answer of the question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this

```
var date= '21/01/2015';
var d=new Date(date.split("/").reverse().join("-"));
var dd=d.getDate();
var mm=d.getMonth()+1;
var yy=d.getFullYear();
var newdate=yy+"/"+mm+"/"+dd;
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tbxon5pn/2/)

Answer (score 24):

Here's the snippet I found working

```js
date="21/01/2015";
var newdate = date.split("/").reverse().join("-");
console.log(newdate)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm... Thanks @Bhargav